# Change getElementById into querySelectorAll in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

In 90% time I face a big problem. The "getElementById" problem. getElementById can use once ad It's connected with id and an id can declare once in html. On the contrary, class is good and can use many time. That's why I always wants to use querySelectorAll instead of getElementById. In my code, how can I replace id to class, so that I can use it as much I need.

```js
   let copyright_date = new Date();
    let copyright_year = copyright_date.getFullYear();
    document.getElementById("copyright-year").innerHTML = copyright_year;
    document.getElementById("site-title").innerHTML = document.title;
```

```html
<p>Copyright <span id="copyright-year"></span> - <a href="#" id="site-title"></a>.</p>
```

I want to change these id into class:  `id="copyright-year"` and `id="site-title"`.

How can I do it using just javascript....?

Comment: Prefer [`textContent`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) over [`innerHTML`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML).

Comment: Why do you even want to change the id? The id is there for unique items on your page. Just use `document.querySelector('#copyright-year')` to select your element. You shouldn't "replace id with class", because you shouldn't try to make general solutions for something really specific, like setting your copyright year.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```html
<p>Copyright <span class="copyright-year"></span> - <a href="#" class="site-title"></a>.</p>


<script type="text/javascript">
  //$("#site-title").click(function(){location.reload()});
  let copyright_date = new Date();
  let copyright_year = copyright_date.getFullYear();

  const copyright_elements = document.querySelectorAll(".copyright-year");
  for (const element of copyright_elements){
    element.innerHTML = copyright_year;
  }

  const site_title_elements = document.querySelectorAll(".site-title");
  for (const element of site_title_elements){
    element.innerHTML = document.title;
  }
</script>
```

However, note that `querySelectorAll` will not return a single element, but an array of elements. So, you have to know which element you want to access specifically.

Comment: I just updated my answer. Can you try it again?

Comment: Wow @NeNad. It works. But I'm not familiar in this technique...

Comment: @AsmaBintaYounus This is just iteration.

Answer (score 1):

This is an attempt with as little code as possible:

```js
[[".copyright-year",(new Date()).getFullYear()],
 [".site-title",document.title]]
 .forEach(([cls,val]) =>document.querySelectorAll(cls).forEach(el=>el.textContent=val));
```

```html
<title>my articles</title>
<p>Copyright <span class="copyright-year"></span> - <a href="#" class="site-title"></a>.</p>
<p>Copyright <span class="copyright-year"></span> - <a href="#" class="site-title"></a>.</p>
```

Admittedly, this is probably a bit much for a Javascript newby. Therefore here are a few explanations

- The array structure `[[...]]` is an array of arrays: two arrays with two elements in it each, a className-based selector string and a *value*.
- The *value* is in the first case the current year and in the second case the document's title.
- The loop with `.forEach(([cls,val])=>...)` over the outer array then uses an ES5 destructuring technique for assigning the elements of each sub-array to the local variables `cls` and `val`.
- And, eventually, the inner loop with `document.querSelectorAll(cls).forEach(el=>...)` brings it all together: each `el`'s `.textContent` is set to the value `val`.

Comment: A new way... But will it work for html elements or just text content...?

Comment: It will work for text content only. I usually define all the HTML structure first and limit the text manipulation operations to just that: text manipulation. This is usually faster than using `.innerHTML`. But, of course, you can substitute `.textContent` for `.innerHTML` and then you can insert any HTLM markup you like.

Comment: Nice way to do it! You earned an upvote :)